# Ordenar el indice de un data.frame después de un filtro en python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Tengo lo siguientes datos con el respectivo índice de un Data Frame:

```
Index Data
1     Si
2     Si
3     No
4     Si
5     No
6     Si
7     No
8     Si
9     No
```

Al momento de filtrar los datos usando `datos.loc[datos['Data'] == 'No']` obtengo lo siguiente:

```
Index Data
3     No
5     No
7     No
9     No
```

La pregunta es, como puedo evitar que después del filtro el índice quede igual, es decir necesito que el Data Frame quede de la siguiente manera:

```
Index Data
1     No
2     No
3     No
4     No
```

Nesecito esto ya que al momento de hacer el pegado de esta info en otro Data Frame, utiliza como llave el indice.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: `.reset_index(drop=True)` te sirve?

Comment: Ey men, eres un genio, me has ayudado bastante, jajajaja.